# Closed form of a recurrence formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, recurrence-relations, recursion

I asked this question earlier by I was told that the statement was not clear so I tried to reword it.

Basically I am given a grid Ai(m x n), for any i natural, I am given the first terms on how the grid grows and I want to generalize it and find a formula for $i = n$ I was able to find a recursive definition but I am not sure how to convert it to a closed form.

First terms of the grid
$$A0(1 X 1)$$
$$A1(1 X 3)$$
$$A2(3 X 3)$$
$$A3(3 X 7)$$
$$A4(7 X 7)$$
$$....$$

I got to the point where I deduced that:

If n even: The base case is for A(0) = 1, A(1) = 1 and $a(n+2) = 2a(n) +1$

For n odd: The base case is  A(0) = 1, A(1) = 3 and $a(n+2) = 2a(n) +1$

so that I don't know how to proceed and get a get closed-form that would represent my problem.

Comment: what is $a(n)$?

Comment: @sortai the sequence that I had for even numbers is 1 1 3 3 7 7 15 15
So the recursive definition is a(1) =1, a(0) = 1,  a(n+2)=2a(n)+1
Or I'm I mistaken?

Comment: what about m? you're trying to find n and m for a given i, right?

Comment: Yes  That's What I try to find

Answer (score 1):

The solution of the recurrence $a(n+2)=2 a(n)+1$ with $a(0)=b$ and $a(1)=c$ can be written as
$$ a(n) = -1 + (1+(-1)^n) (b+1) 2^{n/2-1}  + (1-(-1)^n) (c+1) 2^{n/2 - 3/2}$$

Comment: Can you direct me on a way to find the solution?